# Writing and Reading data with Azure Service Bus from Azure SQL

Tags: azure-functions, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues, azure-servicebus-topics

I have a UI which displays a page with fields to create an account. There is another page to display the account information. There are two **Azure Functions** called **CreateCustomer** & **GetCustomer** are used for this purpose. To add some scalability when an account is created, I'm planning to introduce a **Azure Service Bus**. When the account is created, the UI would send a **CREATE_CUSTOMER** event to the **Azure Service Bus**. The customer will be created in the **Azure SQL** Database.

What I don't know is how to do the reading of the Account information from **Azure SQL** using the **GetCustomer** Azure Function. I'm thinking about an event called **GET_CUSTOMER** which can be sent to the **ASB** by the UI and the UI will receive the data. The advantage with a asynchronous call through **ASB** is to get some scalability if the database is busy.

Should I use **ASB** (event based) or call the **GetCustomer** Azure Function and retrieve the data synchronously (request/response)?

Comment: I don't think you should be using ASB in this particular scenario. I really don't see the benefit of using ASB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm thinking about an event called GET_CUSTOMER which can be sent to the ASB by the UI and the UI will receive the data. The advantage with a asynchronous call through ASB is to get some scalability if the database is busy.

Getting customer information is a query, not an event.

> Should I use ASB (event based) or call the GetCustomer Azure Function and retrieve the data synchronously (request/response)?

Do **not** use asynchronous messaging to retrieve data for UI. Query the data from the data store.